# I can't get json data in code javascript for google chart (project Python Hello Dashboard sample)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Python Hello Dashboard sample
I can't run this project. This project has some problems,in file index.html:  I can't get variables data type JSON (dict)for DataTable.

```
geodata = {{ data }} // error
geodata="{{data}}" //it is String not type JSON
```

accrue cause errors line google.visualization.DataTable(geodata)
Please help me!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':
   ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

 geodata = {{ data }} // error

 function drawMarkersMap() {
   if (! geodata) return;
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(geodata);

   var options = {
     region: 'US',
     displayMode: 'region',
     resolution: 'provinces',
     width: '800'
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
     document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

it in this link: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#downloadinstalllibraries

Comment: `{{ data }}` is not valid Python, nor is it valid JSON or JavaScript.

Comment: it in https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#viewingdata

Comment: That is a template placeholder, not JSON. It even tells you so in the text above and below that template example.

Comment: Read the **rest** of that page too; the JSON data is generated by a different method further on and passed to the template.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the tutorial more thoroughly.

`{{ data }}` is a template *placeholder*, it is not itself JSON (and nowhere close to valid). Further in the tutorial the placeholder is filled in when rendering the template:

```
@decorator.oauth_required
def get(self):
    data = { 'data': self._bq2geo(bq.Query(QUERY, BILLING_PROJECT_ID)),
             'query': QUERY }
    template = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(render(template, data))
```

The `data` key in the `data` dictionary provides the value to be filled in; the `self._bq2geo()` method generates the JSON value:

```
def _bq2geo(self, bqdata):
    """geodata output for region maps must be in the format region, value.
       Assume the BigQuery query output is in this format and get names from schema.
    """
    logging.info(bqdata)
    columnNameGeo = bqdata['schema']['fields'][0]['name']
    columnNameVal = bqdata['schema']['fields'][1]['name']
    logging.info("Column Names=%s, %s" % (columnNameGeo, columnNameVal))
    geodata = { 'cols': ({'id':columnNameGeo,'label':columnNameGeo,'type':'string'},
      {'id':columnNameVal, 'label':columnNameVal, 'type':'number'})}
    geodata['rows'] = [];
    logging.info(geodata)
    for row in bqdata['rows']:
        newrow = ({'c':[]})
        newrow['c'].append({'v': 'US-'+row['f'][0]['v']})
        newrow['c'].append({'v':row['f'][1]['v']})
        geodata['rows'].append(newrow)
    logging.info('FINAL GEODATA---')
    logging.info(geodata)
    return json.dumps(geodata)
```

The method returns a JSON value, which replaces the `{{ data }}` placeholder string.

Comment: How can I retrieve data from variable data to a valid google.visualization.DataTable

Comment: Follow the tutorial properly, then generate your *own* template that includes JSON data, just as the tutorial does.

Comment: <body>
  data:
  <pre> {{ data }} </pre>
</body>

   Result  data: {"rows": [{"c": [{"v": "US-DC"}, {"v":........
I copy and paste result to google.visualization.DataTable({"rows": [{"c": [{"v": "US-DC"}, {"v":...
it can run , But I do not know how to use variables to perform automatic result